# Undefined variable not shown as error with Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, declaration

Entering and compiling the Java class below did not mark any errors in the code using Eclipse

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        xCase = yCase + 100;
    }
}
```

The identifiers xCase and yCase not defined this couldn't be right, so running the command-line
compiler to check it gave me 2 errors

```
C:\Test>javac Test.java
Test.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                xCase = yCase + 100;
                ^
  symbol:   variable xCase
  location: class Test
  Test.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                xCase = yCase + 100;
                        ^
  symbol:   variable yCase
  location: class Test
  2 errors
```

Why isn't Eclipse showing me these errors?

Comment: What happens if you try to run the code? Are you sure it's actually *built* the code? (Is this within a Java project, and in a source directory?)

Comment: @JonSkeet How can he run the code if its not compiling?

Comment: @PeterRader: Well that's the point - the OP expects compile-time errors, which suggests they're expecting it to be compiled. Maybe automatic compilation has been turned off? By running the code, that would *force* compilation...

Comment: @JonSkeet If eclipse see that its not yet compiled, eclipse compiles automatically and show the errors in the editor.

Comment: @PeterRader Sure, but this feature can be disabled. Jon Skeet is trying to tell you that the OP might have this option disabled, so by asking eclipse to run the code, the compilation would be forced and compile-time errors should come up.

Comment: @PeterRader: That's what I'd expect too, but the OP appears not to be seeing errors, which is why they asked the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the red markers in the View "Markers" first.

Comment: I wasn't aware how a marked error influences other error markings. The first error marking in a Java source file does not have to be the first error [top down] in a source file. Also correcting one error [witch removes the error marking] can show new error markings above or below the corrected line or remove one or more error markings from the file.

Comment: Every marker has sideeffect-errors, if they are shown or not. Eclipse try to understand what are sideeffect-errors and mark do NOT mark them, because they are non radical. In your case, a accessible field may exists in the class `java.lang.Object` so i guess any radical-marker you had was like not finding the specified JDK. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Probably you disable `Project -> Build Automatically`?

Probably you have not configured the JavaJDK/JRE in the preferences properly?

Probably you have disabled errors/warnings in come preference/property page?

Many reasons are thinkable ...

Answer (score 0):

**check** Project > Build Automatically.

Eclipse has a tendency to run the previous java file.. make sure that is not the problem.